# Visual Studio 2012 macros uses VS2010 values

Tags: c#, c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2012

My working computer had Visual Studio 2010 installed previously. It was working fine.

To gain full support for C++11, the 2012 was installed to this computer recently (VS2010 was not removed, since some old project need it).

My problem is:
If I launch VS2012, the Visual Studio user values (e.G. $(VSInstallDir), $(VCInstallDir), $(ExecutablePath) etc.) are the VS2010's values, not the values suitable for VS2012.

What is the reason for it? And how can I solve this problem? The VS2012 must use its' own user values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since multiple installations are there, you can select the Platform Toolset from

`Project Property Pages\ Configuration Properties\General\Platform Toolset`

If it still doesn't work, do the following as last resort:

Edit the following file to change the macros:

`C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\V120\Microsoft.Cpp.Common.props`

For me it is V120. Whatever version it is for you, change it accordingly.

Comment: Try the first solution first.

Comment: 1. Tried to change the platform toolset, it wasn't working. Still the VS2010 values were used in the project.

2. The studio 2012 (V110) has the following folder to the macros: C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\V110\Microsoft.Cpp.Common.props; 
This file contains the right values for VS2012. But the studio 2012 seems not to take over them...

Any other ideas?

Comment: Then I think it may be an installation problem. Registy Values may not have changed. Try reinstallation.

Comment: After reinstalling the issue is the same. What registry values should be changed? Where should I look for them?